# How to create cotton wool?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

How do you make cotton balls fluffy with perhaps some loose bits hanging.   [image]

Comment: It's a good question. Could you tell a bit more about the context? What is it for? How is it going to be rendered? What distance is it going to be viewed from?

Comment: Firstly, it is not for myself, but for someone in Facebook. When others give answers, I will show this page to a guy. Besides, I thought cotton balls are challenging to create and thereby interesting. So, I have got screenshots of nodes for cotton balls and paste them into my scrapbook as in link here. Credits on screenshots are given. Links to sources are included. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1ggss5H_XdWtIZ825iRuUjk7svvzdoPWM-cP1yv4kCCc/

Comment: Besides, I am really interested in cotton wool, especially for future usages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried this, I think it needs more hair work though, to get the fluffy thing. For the material, I've used a *Noise Texture* that I've scaled on one axis to get the stria effect. *Emission* is here to give a bit of luminosity and softness to the object, too much shadow would make it look solid like a stone, it somehow simulates a transparent effect. And at the end a bit of *Transparenc*y, with a *Fresnel* as factor, to make the contour a bit evanescent. The hairs are actually long extruded rectangles with a material that also use a mix of *Diffuse*, *Emission* and *Transparency*.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what the nodes are doing? Why emission? Is this on top of hair particles?

Comment: I forgot to thank you long time ago. Sorry about my lateness.   I am back to this thread. I must remember to put this node tree in my scrapbook. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, I hoped someone would find a better solution but it doesn't look too bad  ;)

Comment: Me ayudo muchísimo tu diseño. Gracias