# How do I make stuffing/cotton balls/poly-fil

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

So I'm rendering what I want my room to look like before I remodel it and I'm gonna do a ceiling of stuffing/cotton balls/poly-fil with LED Lights underneath to get a sorta cloud look with streaks of color through it. I've been trying for days to figure out how to make a material that achieves this desired effect but I cant figure it out. Can anyone help

This is what im trying to make:
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/how-to-create-and-render-clouds-in-blender-cycles  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201071/suggestions-for-fog https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43600/low-lying-fog-bounding-object-rendering-as-solid/43648#43648

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144113/how-to-create-cotton-wool